# AutoML generated container returns 503 immediately (GCP). How to troubleshoot?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm new with containers and stuff, so I apologize in advance.

I trained a Vision model on GCP and exported it as a container (I followed this [here](https://medium.com/@juri.sarbach/how-to-deploy-your-automl-model-in-a-cost-effective-way-5efdd377d4d2)). However, when I host it on Cloud Run, I get an error 503.

```
The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.
```

I see lots of questions on here pertaining to high CPU usage or timeouts, but this happens immediately after a request is sent. Logs indicate that the container (and TF) is starting fine, but that's about it.

Is there any way to get more detailed output from a container? Something like how PHP has `display_errors` for 500s?

Input doesn't seem to change the outcome, but here's my body:

```json
{"instances":[{"image_bytes":{"b64":"<insert base64>"},"key":"5e6668d92b4c8.jpeg"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the best place to go was [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/) to read more detailed logs. I didn't find a whole lot of useful information unfortunately, but it turns out that having HTTP2.0 enabled in my Cloud Run revision was causing it to return 503 with no other warnings...

Answer (score 1):

I have deployed successfully a container with HTTP2 enabled as per [**Cloud Run HTTP2 Official Documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2).

HTTP/2 support in [Cloud Run is in Preview Stage](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) and it is working correctly.

Check Cloud Run **Stackdriver** logs in file /varlog/system to see if there is a container exit reason.

These 503 errors can be caused by server socket timeouts in your code as well as application crashes.

As you have AutoML container, I suppose that the language is Python and the web server is Gunicorn as per [Cloud Run Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages). Gunicorn have a default timeout of 30 seconds, which may fail with the error `[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT` if a request exceeds that timeout. You can add --timeout 0 to the gunicorn invocation to disable the worker timeout entirely.

So I would like to suggest you to first see the Stackdriver Logs to see if you are getting any other errors before disabling HTTP2 as it is working as intended.